# Wildfly 10 won't prefill

Tags: mysql, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm Pretty new to wildfly 10. i have my datasources working and my connector working. i have successfuly connections. i have the prefill setting selected. it just doesn't populate my sql database with any tables.

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="tru$
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://<IP>:3306/DatabaseName?useSSL=false</connection-$
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>500</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensi$
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysq$
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the purpose of prefill.  It is to fill the database connection pool pretty much on startup.  It doesn't create any tables for you.  Usually that is an external process like a SQL script to create the tables.  There are other options such as Hibernate that can create tables on startup but that is a different question.

Comment: thank you so much! my boss forgot about that when explaining jboss to me. any resources on this that you found particularly helpful? i'm going to go start googling now!

Comment: @Mepel - it looks like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Bydefault JBoss will not create any table in Mysql DB schema, you have to deploy application which will create  table in DB schema. Why you are expecting JBoss to create tables in DB schema ?

Comment: my boss has created jboss servers before saying that, it creates sql tables automatically. he isn't giving me a ton of help because he wants me to learn wildfly in and out. i'm just having a bit of a rough time with it. asking the wrong questions! i asked him but he forgot about the hibernate stuff! i just asked him again.